# How I can achieve this sidebar menu with two columns - IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am making an application that needs a side like [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpflI.jpg), I have seen several libraries on GitHub, but they are all on one level and I could adapt to my needs, there is a library or example to do this but using storyboard.

You make a side menu following [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/), but it is only at a level, I need that when I select a row see another menu, like in the picture.

I hope someone can help me with an example of a more fully.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a master detail navigation controller
[Great tutorial - youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_J_r8AKw0k)

[image]

Comment: It's not what I need, I will need a nested sidebar, but thanks for the link.